# Can we have pre selected category or first category selected in Category navigation?

Tags: templates, liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

We are working on a requirement where we need the first category pre-selected in category navigation.Based on the same,the assets should be filtered in an asset publisher based on this.Do we have some means to achieve this using Category ADT.Passing query string would need a hardcoded category id passed with URL,which can change anytime.

Answer (score 0):

The asset publisher can be controlled with public render parameters. a possible "hack" would be to add a query string to Layout configuration that would add a public render parameter when the page is hit.

The second option would be to add an empty portlet to the page that would always publish a public render parameter with the default category and handle the UC when something else was selected.

Note that always only one category can be passed by the public render parameter.

The last option is to make a code change to the asset publisher.